# Functions within Objects in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm trying to put a function within an object in CoffeeScript however when printing the function I get the actual function and not what I've asked it to return.

I am currently learning CoffeeScript so please excuse me if this is a really silly mistake :)

Here is my code:

```
define =
    hello: ->
        Swordling = true
        user = "Swordling" if Swordling
        return user
alert define.hello
```

And here is the result I get:
http://prntscr.com/8wzi6f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes, you're only outputting *the function*, you're not *calling* the function:

```
alert define.hello()
```

Comment: Ohhh! Thank you so much! I didn't think the () was necessary in CoffeeScript. :)

Comment: It is only optional when it's unambiguous by the context whether you're calling the function or just referring to the function. `foo bar` is unambiguously `foo(bar)`, however `foo` could be both `foo` or `foo()`, and it defaults to the former.